# i want to get the value which was there in the above array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

```
print_r("</br>");
print_r($ptidz);

foreach ($techniques as $key => $tech)
{
    if (in_array($tech['tech_id'], $ptidz)) {
        print_r("</br>");
        print_r($tech['tech_id']);
        print_r($tech['tech_name']);
    }
}
```

im getting output like this:

```
<br>
Array ( [0] => 48 [1] => 2 [2] => 45 )<br> 
2Apple<br>
45lemon<br>
48berry 
<br>
```

But i want to prioritize based on the $ptidz value
e.g.:

```
48 berry<br>
2 apple<br>
45 lemon<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi see this example,

```
<?php
    $fruits = array("45"=>"lemon", "37"=>"orange", "98"=>"banana", "2"=>"apple");
    ksort($fruits);
    foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
    }
    ?>
```

The above example will output:

**2 = apple 37 = orange 45 = lemon 98 = banana**

May this help you

Answer (score 0):

then you need to sort the array to priotize it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php